# Oracle SQL - Writing a join with count query

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I am currently working on logging the number of users in a database that have logged in during the last year.

This is the example schema I am working with: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7dfb6/15 (copied below)

I have these two queries:

Query 1:

```
select distinct userid from tosuser tu;
```

Query 2:

```
select count (*) from tosevent te where te.LASTUPDATEDATE BETWEEN 
to_date('01/01/2014', 'dd/mm/yyyy') AND to_date('31/12/2014', 'dd/mm/yyyy');
```

That I was hoping to join, to give a result like this:

```
USERNAME    COUNT
FRED         7
MARY         2
```

Where count refers to the number of logins the user made in the last year. (I am currently passing the year as a java parameter)

The closest thing I have working is this:

```
select distinct username, LASTUPDATEDATE from tosuser tu, tosevent te where 
te.LASTUPDATEDATE BETWEEN 
to_date('01/01/2014', 'dd/mm/yyyy') AND to_date('31/12/2014', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
and te.username = tu.userid and tu.userenabled='1' and tu.userid!='OASIS';
```

Which gives me each login event. 
Was just wondering if you know how I would write this query using Oracle syntax?

---

Schema from SQL fiddle if that dissapears:

```
CREATE TABLE tosuser ( userid     VARCHAR2(30) PRIMARY KEY, IsDeleted    INT NOT NULL, UserEnabled    INT,ExternalUser  INT);

CREATE TABLE tosevent ( id      VARCHAR2(30) PRIMARY KEY, username VARCHAR2(30), DATA3 VARCHAR2(30), LASTUPDATEDATE DATE  );

INSERT into tosuser (userid, IsDeleted, UserEnabled, ExternalUser) values ('OASIS',1,1,1);    
INSERT into tosuser (userid, IsDeleted, UserEnabled, ExternalUser) values ('FRED',1,1,1);
INSERT into tosuser (userid, IsDeleted, UserEnabled, ExternalUser) values ('MARY',1,1,1);
INSERT into tosuser (userid, IsDeleted, UserEnabled, ExternalUser) values ('TOM',1,1,1);
INSERT into tosuser (userid, IsDeleted, UserEnabled, ExternalUser) values ('MICHEAL',1,1,1);

INSERT into tosevent (id, username, DATA3, LASTUPDATEDATE) values (1,'FRED','successful logon',to_date('08/09/2014', 'dd/mm/yyyy'));
INSERT into tosevent (id, username, DATA3, LASTUPDATEDATE) values (2,'FRED','successful logon',to_date('09/09/2014', 'dd/mm/yyyy'));
INSERT into tosevent (id, username, DATA3, LASTUPDATEDATE) values (3,'FRED','successful logon',to_date('10/09/2014', 'dd/mm/yyyy'));
INSERT into tosevent (id, username, DATA3, LASTUPDATEDATE) values (4,'FRED','successful logon',to_date('11/09/2014', 'dd/mm/yyyy'));
INSERT into tosevent (id, username, DATA3, LASTUPDATEDATE) values (5,'FRED','successful logon',to_date('12/09/2014', 'dd/mm/yyyy'));
INSERT into tosevent (id, username, DATA3, LASTUPDATEDATE) values (6,'MARY','successful logon',to_date('08/09/2014', 'dd/mm/yyyy'));
INSERT into tosevent (id, username, DATA3, LASTUPDATEDATE) values (7,'MARY','successful logon',to_date('09/09/2014', 'dd/mm/yyyy'));
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just want a `group by`:

```
select username, count(*)
from tosuser tu join
     tosevent te 
     on te.username = tu.userid
where te.LASTUPDATEDATE BETWEEN to_date('01/01/2014', 'dd/mm/yyyy') AND
                                to_date('31/12/2014', 'dd/mm/yyyy') and
      tu.userenabled = '1' and tu.userid <> 'OASIS'
group by username;
```

You need to be careful using dates.  If the `LastUpdateDate` has a time component, then you want to phrase this as:

```
where te.LASTUPDATEDATE >= date '2014-01-01' and te.LASTUPDATEDATE < date '2015-01-01'
```

You can also write this just by looking at the year:

```
where extract(year from LASTUPDATEDATE) = 2014
```

However, this version may not use indexes as effectively as the previous version.

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks a million for your answer, just tested your query and that did exactly what I need it to do, thank you :) Will take your advice into account, I'm pretty sure that the LASTUPDATEDATE has no time component but will check it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `DISTINCT` that way, because it applies to ALL fields in the `SELECT`, not just to the following one. 
You should be using `GROUP BY`:

```
select username, LASTUPDATEDATE
from tosuser tu, tosevent te 
where 
te.LASTUPDATEDATE BETWEEN to_date('01/01/2014', 'dd/mm/yyyy') AND to_date('31/12/2014', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
and te.username = tu.userid 
and tu.userenabled='1' 
and tu.userid!='OASIS'
GROUP BY username
```

As a somewhat related comment, if you ever see something like:

```
select distinct(foo), bar ...
```

then you should review that query as it is probably not doing what it is meant to do. That `SELECT` means the same as

```
select distinct foo, bar ...
```

Comment: Hi gpeche, thanks very much for your answer and your advice, will take that on board!